# Error when inserting into table SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**EDIT**

I re did everything. But now I get this error:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
>   String or binary data would be truncated.
>   The statement has been terminated.

I know I Need to change a value but don't know which one. Here is the table:

```
USE MasterAddress
Create Table CompanyAddress1
(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,CompanyName varchar (MAX)
    ,CompanyNumber varchar (MAX)
    ,RegAddress_CareOf varchar(MAX)
    ,RegAddress_POBox varchar (MAX)
    ,RegAddress_AddressLine1 varchar (MAX)
    ,RegAddress_AddressLine2 varchar(MAX)
    ,RegAddress_PostTown varchar (MAX)
    ,RegAddress_County varchar(MAX)
    ,RegAddress_Country varchar(MAX)
    ,RegAddress_PostCode varchar (15)
    ,CompanyCategory varchar (MAX)
    ,CompanyStatus varchar (MAX)
    ,CountryOfOrigin varchar
    ,DissolutionDate date
    ,IncorporationDate date
    ,Accounts_AccountRefDay tinyint
    ,Accounts_AccountRefMonth tinyint
    ,Accounts_AccountsNextDueDate date
    ,Accounts_AccountsLastMadeUpDate date
    ,Accounts_AccountCategory varchar (MAX)
    ,[Returns_NextDueDate] date
    ,[Returns_LastMadeUpDate] date
    ,Mortgages_NumMortCharges int
    ,Mortgages_NumMortOutstanding int
    ,Mortgages_NumMortPartSatisfied int
    ,Mortgages_NumMortSatisfied int
    ,SICCode_SicText_1 varchar (MAX)
    ,SICCode_SicText_2 varchar (MAX)
    ,SICCode_SicText_3 varchar (MAX)
    ,SICCode_SicText_4 varchar (MAX)
    ,LimitedPartnerships_NumGenPartners varchar(MAX)
    ,LimitedPartnerships_NumLimPartners varchar(MAX)
    ,URI varchar (MAX)
    ,PreviousName_1CONDATE varchar (MAX)
    ,PreviousName_1CompanyName varchar (MAX)
    ,PreviousName_2CONDATE varchar (MAX)
    ,PreviousName_2CompanyName varchar (MAX)
    ,PreviousName_3CONDATE varchar (MAX)
    ,PreviousName_3CompanyName varchar (MAX)
);
```

And here is the insert:

```
 INSERT INTO CompanyAddress1
    VALUES (
    'BARDOG NEW OPCO LIMITED OPCO LIMITED'
    ,'5843995'  
    ,NULL   
    ,NULL   
    ,'SUITE 555 SECOND FLOOR'
    ,'DESIGN CENTRE EAST MILL'  
    ,'YORK' 
    ,NULL
    ,NULL   
    ,'P05T K0DE'    
    ,'Private Limited Company'
    ,'Active'   
    ,'United Kingdom'   
    ,NULL   
    ,'2006-06-2006' 
    ,31
    ,12 
    ,'2015-09-30'   
    ,'2013-12-31'
    ,'FULL' 
    ,'2015-07-19'   
    ,'2014-07-14'   
    ,0  
    ,0  
    ,0  
    ,0  
    ,'74990 - Non-trading company'  
    ,'86900 - Other human health activities'
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,0  
    ,0  
    ,'http://biszness.data.gov/id/company/05843995'
    ,NULL
    ,NULL   
    ,NULL   
    ,NULL   
    ,NULL   
    ,NULL
    );
```

Comment: What's the reason for quoting `"Returns_NextDueDate" date` ?

Comment: When I created it the word Returns wasn't allowed, and only worked when i enclosed like that

Comment: Start adding em one at a time and see where it breaks.

Comment: @ThomasSharp RETURN is a reserved word, but hardly "Returns_NextDueDate". Anyways, you should enclose it with `[ ]` then: `[Returns_NextDueDate] date`

Comment: @ThomasSharp Edited my answer to match your edit

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an error here `'2006-06-25',31,12,'2015-09-30'`

If we take a look at your create

```
,DissolutionDate date
,IncorporationDate date
,Accounts_AccountRefDay tinyint
,Accounts_AccountsNextDueDate date
,Accounts_AccountsLastMadeUpDate date
```

There is only 1 tiny int and then dates. In your insert, which follows the same order as your create, there is  `31,12` and then another date

Therefor you are trying to add 12 in `Accounts_AccountsNextDueDate`

**Let me know if it works or not and I can look to see if there is another error**

EDIT : The order you enter your values is still wrong

```
VALUES
    ('BARDOG NEW OPCO LIMITED','5555555',NULL,NULL,'SUITE 555 SECOND FLOOR',    
    'DESIGN CENTRE EAST MILL','YORK',NULL,NULL,'PO5T K0DE', 
    'Private Limited Company','Active','United Kingdom',NULL, '2006-06-25',31,'2015-09-30','2015-09-30',    
    'FULL','2015-05-30','2014-06-25',0,0,0,0,'74990-Non-trading company', '86900 - Other human health activities',NULL, NULL,
    0,0, 'http://business/company/11111111',NULL,NULL,NULL, 12                                                      

);
```

Your fist date entry happens at the 15th element.

```
    (CompanyName 
    ,CompanyNumber 
    ,RegAddress_CareOf 
    ,RegAddress_POBox 
    ,RegAddress_AddressLine1 
    ,RegAddress_AddressLine2 
    ,RegAddress_PostTown 
    ,RegAddress_County 
    ,RegAddress_PostCode 
    ,CompanyCategory 
    ,CompanyStatus  
    ,CountryOfOrigin 
    ,DissolutionDate 
    ,IncorporationDate 
    ,Accounts_AccountRefDay
```

In your insert order your first date is at the 13th element. **You are inserting a date into** `,Accounts_AccountRefDay` (The 15th element which is a tinyint)

I would suggest rewriting your entire VALUES part

Comment: I havn't double checked, but ... there is no reason that the insert should follow the same order as the create. As long as the insert fields and values match, there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: His insert follows the same order as the create so his values should too

Comment: If that is the case, yes. But then you should edit your answer to reflect that. Skip the referal to the create, and instead refer to the actual insert (i.m.o.) :)

Comment: I added the mention of both following the same order but kepts the create as it states more clearly which fields is a date and which is the tinyint. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

See the [MSDN article about `char[(n)]` and `varchar[(n)]` data types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx).  If `n` is not specified, `n` is assumed to be 1.  Therefore, your definition of `CountryOfOrigin varchar` limits that column to 1 character.

You can see this in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns`:

```
select * from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'CompanyAddress1'
and column_name = 'CountryOfOrigin'
```

The result shows that the `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` is 1.  Your INSERT statement is putting `'United Kingdom'` into it.  This is what causes the error `String or binary data would be truncated.`

If you fix this, your `INSERT` statement will next generate the following error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting
>   date and/or time from character string.

This is because of the string `'2006-06-2006'` being inserted into the `date` column `IncorporationDate`.  Fixing this will cause the query to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

For you not to have trouble in doing DML commands for a Table in SQL Server there's a shortcut for it, and all you need to do is change the values you want
Right Click the Table on your database then Click on **Script Table As** then Choose what action you want (Insert To, Update To, Delete To,etc.)